# Convert epoch timestamp to datetime without milliseconds?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, epoch

First of all I know there are several questions out there similar to this, but none of them actually show how to display the date time format without including milliseconds.

I have this code below:

```
SELECT CONVERT(
   DATETIME,
   dateadd(SS,CONVERT(INT, 1354320000), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' as datetime)),
   120
)
```

However, the code is including milliseconds but rather I need the format to be like such `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Does anyone know an effective way to go about this?

Comment: [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Using `datetime2(0)` instead of `datetime` is also an option.

Comment: Ahh bingo!, dont know how I didnt think about those. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use an appropriate data type. As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types), the return value data type for `DATEADD()` is dynamic and it depends on the argument supplied for the `date` parameter.

```
SELECT DATEADD(
   second, 
   CONVERT(int, 1354320201), 
   CAST('1970-01-01T00:00:00' AS datetime2(0))
)
```

Result:

```
2012-12-01 00:03:21
```

Answer (score 1):

Try **SMALL DATETIME**

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SS,CONVERT(INT, 1354320000), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME))AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Also, By using **FORMAT**

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(SS,CONVERT(INT, 1354320000), CAST('1970-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```